# Replicating data through Voids

Tags: c#

Been trying to figure out how i can get "sum" and "reg" to go throughout the whole application without the user having to continually Input. (sorry im bad at explaining stuff so go easy on me please)

```
using RiotSharp;
using RiotSharp.Misc;
using RiotSharp.SummonerEndpoint;

namespace WindowsFormsApp3
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private static RiotApi api = ("nolooky");
        public string sum;
        public string reg;

        public void sumShit()
        {   
            reg = sumReg.Text;
            sum = sumInput.Text;
            try
            {
                if (reg == "")
                {
                }
                else if (sum == "")
                {
                    errLabel.Text = "PLEASE INSERT SUMMONER NAME!";
                    errLabel.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.OrangeRed;
                }
                else if (reg == "OCE" && sum != null)
                {
                    var regOCE = RiotSharp.Misc.Region.oce;
                    var summoner = api.GetSummonerByName(regOCE, sum);
                    MessageBox.Show(summoner.Id.ToString());
                }
                else if (reg == "NA" && sum != null)
                {
                    var regNA = RiotSharp.Misc.Region.na;
                }   
                return;
            }
            catch (RiotSharpException)
            {
                errLabel.Text = "SUMMONER NOT FOUND!";
                errLabel.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.OrangeRed;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

i wanna be able to use the summoner.Id in different voids but it just doesn't let me. Again sorry for the bad explanation. But thanks for your help.

Comment: Post the code with method name  and if possible class and namespace as well

Comment: Would this edit be more useful?

Comment: In your code, `sum` will never be `null`. You can remove that check.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that I understand what you want, but I think that you can create class with `summoner` as a static field, and than you can call `summoner` throughout the whole application as ClassName.summoner (but be sure you give `summoner` a value before using it).

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to achieve this. One of the way, declare it as you have declared reg

```
public string reg;
public object summoner;
```

And use the same

```
else if (reg == "OCE" && sum != null)
{
    var regOCE = RiotSharp.Misc.Region.oce;
    summoner = api.GetSummonerByName(regOCE, sum);
    MessageBox.Show(summoner.Id.ToString());
}
```

Now you can use the summoner anywhere throughout your code.

**Note**:overhead is involved due to boxing and unboxing as its not clear what's the type is your api returning. If you know the exact type replace it with the object keyword.